# angular 7 with viewer having signature feature

Tags: angular7, viewer

I work with angular 7

I'm looking for a viewer which open the most extension files like : pdf,image,word,powerpoint...
and the most important thing this viewer contain the signature feature.

I try to use pdftron viewer but it has a  problem with signature feature ( can not be saved ) ad has problem with word document
I try also with pspdfkit but it open only pdf document.
can someone help me to find a viewer which open more than
 one extension and has a signature feature

Answer (score 0):

I’m part of the PSPDFKit for Web team. Our solution supports signatures and we have an online demo available to try at https://web-examples.pspdfkit.com/signatures. We are actively working on and will be supporting server side conversion of MS Office files to PDF this year, so you would be able to handle those files as well when launched.

We will be happy to answer any question you have at https://support.pspdfkit.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Instead of providing a programmatic solution, running a marketing campaign, is NOT good.